# How to turn on and off "out of office" reply for a specific duration(date) in outlook 2007?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007

How to turn on and off "out of office" reply for a specific duration(date) in outlook 2007?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an option to do this in the out of office assistant dialogue.